# gas ругается на fldq (синтаксис AT&T)

Tags: ассемблер, gnu

Хочу загрузить double из стека:

```
fldq    12(%ebp)
```

однако компилятор ругается: **Error: invalid instruction suffix for `fld'**

В чём проблема?

Comment: А вы документацию на fldq читали?

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет, не читал. Хотя искал в инете - ничего толком не нашёл. А она должна чем-то принципиально отличаться от **fldl** и **fldt**? Эти две работают же...

Comment: С **fstq** и **fstpq** такая же история. Он ещё **fstt** не знает (а вот **fstpt** работает нормально)...

Comment: Разобрался я с **fldq**, **fstq**, **fstpq**!
Оказывается, **fldl**, **fstl**, **fstpl** генерят инструкции с **qword ptr**, а для генерации **dword ptr** нужно писать **flds**, **fsts**, **fstps**.
Вот это тупняк! AT&T жжот просто!

Что же касается **fstt**, то инструкция **fst**, оказывается, вообще не работает с **tbyte ptr** (по спецификации Intel - посмотрел в справочнике), а вот **ftsp** работает!
Вот такая петрушка :)